# Tips and advice on how to make an eclipse source-to-source compiler plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I have been searching for this but I could use a bit of help. I am not even sure if a plugin is the way to go with this.

Anyway, here is a description of what I want to do:

I have developed a `Java` project which is a `source-to-source compiler`. It translates `Java` files with `jQuery` blocks into `Java-only` files. It accepts a file from the `cli` arguments, `transpiles` it and `outputs` the result to a new file. I used `ANTLR` for this.

Now that the program is working, I would like to make some sort of plugin which makes use of it. Just like we can create a new `Java` project, code and run the program in eclipse, I would like to be able to create a new `JavaWithJQuery` project, be able to code, and when I run it with eclipse,  it would use the project I made to transpile it and run it directly, instead of outputting a file with `Java`-only.

Is this possible? I would appreciate some tips, and advice on how to get started.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: @PrerakSola I have edited my question to remove those requests

Comment: I think you would have to define your own builder for that. [PDE docs](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_builders.htm) can introduce you to the task. You could have a look at how [AJDT builder](http://git.eclipse.org/c/ajdt/org.eclipse.ajdt.git/tree/org.eclipse.ajdt.core/src/org/eclipse/ajdt/core/builder/AJBuilder.java) or original [Java builder](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/builder/JavaBuilder.java.html) works for inspiration.